# Метод renameTo переименовывает даже если имя существует

Tags: java, android

Дано:
в папке два файла:

- newName.txt
- newName2.txt

Пытаюсь переименовать newName.txt в newName2.txt

Если прогоняю данный метод на Windows в идее, то возвращается как и ожидаю false и ничего не происходит.

Но если прогоняю тесты в Android Studio на эмуляторе, то в папке остается только файл с именем newName2.txt

```
String newFilePath = file.getParentFile() + "/" + newName;

renameTo(file, newFilePath);

private boolean renameTo(File file, String newName){
        return file.renameTo(new File(newName));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) говорит, что поведение метода `File.renameTo()` платформозависимо (platform-specific). Значит, результат его выполнения может отличаться в разных ОС, что вы и наблюдаете. Та же документация рекомендует использовать метод [`Files.move()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) для платформонезависимого переименования файлов. В частности, в `Files.move()` можно явно указать, хотите ли вы перезаписать файл, лежащий по новому пути. По умолчанию `Files.move()` упадёт, если файл с указанным именем уже существует. Правда, класс [`Files`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) в Android появился лишь в API level 26 (Android 8.0), так что если вы разрабатываете приложение под младшие версии, вам стоит явным образом проверять, существует ли файл по тому пути, по которому вы хотите его переместить (переименовать).